# Can MongoDB complex Stored Procedures work with Java web services

Tags: java, objective-c, swift, mongodb, java-stored-procedures

I am planning to start develop an iOS application .Would like to use MongoDB as my database.I have lot of complex stored procedures to write with Join Queries.
Am new to MongoDB and absolutely no idea how stored procedures work in MongoDB.and am using Java Rest webservices to call my DB.
Any advice from professionals will be appreciated !.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb is a NoSQL database program, instead of classic tables it stores the data in JSON like documents with schemas, which means it is no possible to have stored procedures in it or use SQL commands like Joins. You won't be able to use what you want to. What you'll have to do is store your data, retrieve it from your schemas and then make your own relationships handly. So, if you are planning to work with sorted and related data with complex stored procedures, MongoDB is not good choice.